# Phaser: Angular Movement

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've started tinkering in Phaser.io and so far I have a sprite that moves forward automatically, and can move left and right in a straight line.

What I now want to achieve is an angular movement rather than moving in a straight line. I have looked at the "Tanks" example and saw how they achieve the effect there, but it doesn't seem to have any effect in my game. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

```
function update() {

    player.body.setZeroVelocity();

    player.body.moveUp(300)

    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        player.angle -= 4;
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        player.angle += 4;
    }

}
```

The code runs with no errors, and the sprite automatically moved forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you function `moveUp` you could use [velocityFromAngle](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#velocityFromAngle).

Something like this:

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 800, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });


var player;

function preload() {
    game.load.image('player', 'notfonud');
}

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    player = this.game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX,500, 'player');
    player.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);

    game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
    player.body.allowRotation = true; 
    player.angle = -90;
}

function update() {

    if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT)){
        player.angle -= 5;
    }
    else if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT)){
        player.angle += 5;
    }
  
    game.physics.arcade.velocityFromAngle(player.angle, 50, player.body.velocity)
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div id="game"></div>
```